# Getting a crime 'count' from pandas big dataset

Tags: python, pandas, loops, bigdata

This is quite a broad question because I can't copy all the different things I have tried. From this dataset of NYPD crime: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Complaint-Data-Historic/qgea-i56i

I am trying to iterate through the CMPLNT_FR_DT row, (which is a string and defies and transformation into DateTime object)

to create a data frame and fill it with values so that it looks like the following:

```
[Date]                        [Borough]              [Crime Count]       
01-01-2014
...

...

...

12-31-2014
```

so a sample row would look like:

```
05-23-2014   QUEENS     45
```

and represent that on the 23rd of May 2014, 45 crimes occurred in Queens.

I have pickled the dataset for quicker processing time. I'm using the python pandas library. My issues have been that I cannot seem to iterate through CMPLNT_FR_DT no matter how hard I try to get a crime count. Neither can I use the `set_value` function to set values from the NYPD_Historic data frame to my new one.  Moreover, even trying to count borough incidents using `.iterrows()` yields a 'Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex ' error. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It might be a good idea to show us your code so that we have a clearer picture of what you're doing

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this would be a very good time to use the groupby method.  You could implement `df.groupby(['CMPLNT_FR_DT', 'Borough']).count()`, which will give you a new dataframe with a count of all of the instances with the same date and borough regardless of the format of the date so long as they are all the same data type.

As an added benefit, this will be much, much quicker than iterating through the entire dataframe.